# Is it possible to search Wikipedia including deleted text?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

It is possible to perform search on [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org), which includes history along with current page content.
It would be especially good to search in deleted articles or deleted passages of articles.

(If no, is it possible to do so with at least [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) engine?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a Wikipedia Revision History Search here;

http://wikipedia.ramselehof.de/wikiblame.php?project=wikipedia&lang=en

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Its interesting! do you know is it possible to use this engine with any wikimedia engine?

Comment: Yes, just change the text in the 'Project' field to the one you'd like to search (http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Complete_list_of_Wikimedia_projects)

Answer (score 6):

Wikimedia provides dumps [0], wich depending of your intention, can be helpfull. Delected revisions or articles aren't shown on those dumps nor are publicly avaiable, but depending of the objective, it's possible to request access to non-public data. [1]

[0]- https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps

[1]- https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Access_to_non-public_data

Answer (score 3):

There is also an archive of deleted Wikipedia articles called [Deletionpedia](http://deletionpedia.dbatley.com/w/index.php?title=Main_Page). The archive is updated by an automated bot, which saves copies of the pages prior to their deletion (thus saving them from permanent destruction).

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that this archive has not been updated for a long time. I will continue searching for recent archives of deleted Wikipedia articles, and post them here if I find any.

Comment: There is a [Speedy Deletion Wikia](http://speedydeletion.wikia.com) which archives articles that are scheduled for deletion.